# Rails Search and Category Dropdown (No Method Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following in my `events` controller:

```
def index
  @event = Event.search(params[:search]).events_by_category(params[:cat]).order(...).paginate(...)
end
```

And in my `events` model, I have the following class method:

```
def self.events_by_category(cat)
  if cat == 0
    all
  elsif cat && cat != 0
    where('category = ?', cat)
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

And in my view I have a standard search box for the search and dropdown for the category selection. The category `options_for_select` has an array that includes `["All Categories", 0]` in it.

My question is: Why does this return no results instead of all results when All Categories is selected in the dropdown. And, when I change the array to `["All Categories", "ALL"]` and the if statement to `if cat == "ALL"` it returns `Undefined method 'order'`?

I think it has something to do with stringing the search and events_by_category together in the controller, but searches and categories work just fine in conjunction when it's not All Categories being selected...

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question first: the problem is that your `cat == "ALL"` condition returns `Event.all`, which is a Ruby `Array`, not an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html). [`order`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) is an activerecord method not an array method, that's why you're getting the error `Undefined method 'order'`.

If you want to return all results for the category `ALL`, then change `all` to `scoped` (which will return a scope with no conditions on it). That will be chainable, so that you can call it with `order` and `paginate`.

As to your first question, `params[:cat]` is a string so you should be checking whether `cat == "0"` not `cat == 0`. I think that should solve the problem.

Your conditional, by the way, is a bit convoluted: you're testing if `cat` is 0, then checking that it is not 0 in the else statement, but you already know that it is not 0. I'd suggest simplifying your method code to this:

```
def self.events_by_category(cat)
  (cat && cat != "0") ? where('category = ?', cat) : scoped
end
```

This says: if the category is present and not `"0"` (i.e. not the category "all results"), then return results for that category, if not return all results.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I used scope for the second else and for some reason that didn't click when I used `all`. And, thank you for refactoring the code, too!

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.events_by_category(cat)
 if cat == "0"
   all
 elsif cat && cat != "0"
   where('category = ?', cat)
 else
   scoped
 end
end
```

The above will work.

Comment: No this will not work, for the reason I describe below: `all` returns an array, so when it is called with `order` it will raise an error.